# Eclipse & Sharepoint

Tags: eclipse, sharepoint, eclipse-plugin

I wanted to check with you guys if anyone knows an Eclipse plugin that can integrate SharePoint onto it. I did a lot of research and couldn't find any.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use it [over WebDAV](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-team/target.php).

But please don't tell me you want to store source code in Sharepoint?

Comment: Actually, kinda... The company I work on doesn't want to spend money on any kind of source file repository for some time.
So, in the mean time, they wanted to use SharePoint. It's not good at all, I told them, but still...

Comment: When all you have is a hammer... ;)

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail

Comment: I've been having a lot of discussions about this and previously mentioned the solutions you're proposing as well. However, they don't really want to go with other option, they're blinded with SharePoint. Their problem is also to setup an environment and so on. 
I'll see how to convince them. 

Thanks again!